# How to invoke a job in a spring batch application in pcf?

Tags: task, scheduled-tasks, spring-batch, job-scheduling

I want to design a invoker (Java spring core based independent jar) such that when the invoker is called from a Linux script it invokes a job which has been integrated in a spring batch application, staged on a platform like Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

Right now I am using a spring boot application to perform this operation using org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.task.TaskLauncher;

```
TaskLauncher.launchTask(appDeploymentRequest).
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci The question is how to create a spring core independent jar to invoke jobs in a spring batch as a task and given that the spring batch is staged on PCF?